# WSO2 and Positional DATA

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 ESB and i can't seem to find a way to work with **positional data** (raw txt file), do you have any clue on how to do that? **Thanks in advance**.

Comment: Check this - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+271%3A+File+Processing

Comment: @Pubci In the samples presented in this link, only the Smooks seem adapted to my need. I tried using them but in vain. thx